# Inspecting a browser's Developer Tools

Tags: user-interface, colors, google-chrome-devtools, uicolor, safari-web-inspector

Rather than inspecting a website I'm visiting, I'd like to inspect the Dev Tools themselves. I'd like to do this, as I'm trying to obtain the color values for the colors used in Dev Tools to depict an element's `content-box`, `padding`, `border` and `margin`.

Does anyone know how I might do this in Chrome or Safari, or have an alternative method for obtaining these color values from Dev Tools?

[image]

Comment: So, you want the color values of those boxes in your screenshot?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. I was able to obtain the RGBA values of the box model using this method. TY.